# Как растянуть кнопку на всю ширину экрана?

Tags: java, android

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
   tools:context="com.example.asus.hackaton.view.examview.remindersview.RemindersFragment">



    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/text_view_morning"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
        android:text="Утро " />


              <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_morning_time"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Введите"
                android:textStyle="bold" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/text_view_evening"
                android:text="Вечер "/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_evening_time"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Введите"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="Сохранить"
            android:id="@+id/save_button"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored" />

    </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Как кнопку "save_button" растянуть на весь экран?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Точно также как и любую другую вьюху - задав ей ширину во весь родительский контейнер - `match_parent`

В вашем случае кнопку для этого надо вынести из нынешнего родителя, который не даёт ей расшириться ибо сам имеет ширину по содержимому. При этом, для сохранения положения надо задать нынешнему родителю ID и указать кнопке быть снизу нынешнего родителя через атрибут `android:layout_below`

Comment: Это прямо отличнейший ответ, но задав match_parent он не растягивается на весь экран в данном случае)

Comment: @MartinezToni, это потому, что она лежит в LinearLayout, у которого ширина по содержимому. Вынесите кнопку за пределы его нынешнего родителя

Comment: Тогда кнопка сместиться в ненужное мне положение.

Comment: @MartinezToni, да, если вы не укажите ей быть под её нынешним родителем. Для этого надо задать оному ID, а кнопке указать `layoutBelow` или `layoutAbove`

Comment: Укажите это в ответе. И вопрос будет закрыт.

Answer (score 1):

Виджет можно растянуть (по ширине или по высоте) только в пределах родительского контейнера.

Задавая атрибут `android:layout_width="match_parent"` кнопке `save_button` можно растянуть данную кнопку по ширине родительского `ViewGroup`, в данном случае, по ширине `LinearLayout`.

Так как родительский `ViewGroup` для данной кнопки имеет атрибут `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`, то кнопка не будет растянута по ширине всего экрана.

Чтобы растянуть кнопку по ширине всего экрана, нужно задать атрибут `android:layout_width="match_parent"` у родительского для кнопки `save_button` `ViewGroup` – `LinearLayout`.